# can you help whi console log?

Tags: javascript

i need to count X and Y
but my console log dosent work, maybe problem in
if matches[i].includes(something) == "true"

```
    var input = "10W5N2S6E";
var matches = input.split(/(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)/);
for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  if (matches[i].includes("w") == "true") {
    x = x - matches[i];
    console.log(x);
  }
  if (matches[i].includes("e") == "true") {
    x = x + matches[i];
    console.log(x);
  }
  if (matches[i].includes("n") == "true") {
    y = y + matches[i];
    console.log(y);
  }
  if (matches[i].includes("s") == "true") {
    y = y - matches[i];
    console.log(y);
  }
}
```

Comment: Comparation ` == "true"` is not needed and it could be `true` without `"`. You can just `if (matches[i].includes("s"))`.

Comment: `.includes()` is case-sensitive.

Comment: `.includes()` returns `true` or `false` (booleans), not `"true"` or `"false"` (strings). Also, `if(a == true)` is equivalent to `if(a)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to to use `toLowerCase()` since `includes()` is case sensitive.

Also, no need to compare `includes() == "true"` since it returns a boolean and it is enough for the if condition (which will execute the next block statement based on that boolean condition)

```js
var input = "10W5N2S6E";
var matches = input.split(/(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)/);
for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  const match = matches[i].toLowerCase();
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  if (match.includes("w")) {
    x = x - matches[i];
    console.log(x);
  }
  if (match.includes("e")) {
    x = x + matches[i];
    console.log(x);
  }
  if (match.includes("n")) {
    y = y + matches[i];
    console.log(y);
  }
  if (match.includes("s")) {
    y = y - matches[i];
    console.log(y);
  }
}
```

Comment: Outputs 1 and 3 are `NaN` ?

Comment: This is due to the line:
x = x - matches[i]; // x is number and matches[i] is a string
I don't understand what the code is supposed to do so i only commented and refactored the obvious mistakes and what was clear to me